# Getting rid of semicolon in vancouver style bib file when using @Webpage

Tags: bibtex, punctuation

As the title says, I am getting an extraneous semicolon after the `type` entry when using `vancouver` style bibtex. Here is the example `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{amsart}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[bookmarks, bookmarksopen, bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{216 mm}
\setlength{\paperheight}{279 mm}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.96}

\sloppypar

\begin{document}

\title[]{title}

\author{Authors TBD}

\maketitle

A citation~\cite{arXiv-web}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}

\bibliography{ex}
\end{document}
```

And the `.bib` file is:

```
@Webpage{arXiv-web,
    type={page on the Internet},
    title={arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    key={arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    url={http://arxiv.org},
    note = {Accessed: 2014-02-03}
}
```

The result is:

> [1] arXiv.org e-Print archive [page on the Internet];. Available from: http://arxiv.org. Accessed: 2014-02-03.

Thanks for any suggestions to get rid of the `;` after the `[page on the Internet]` entry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of the semicolon, the `type` field must be (as required by the Vancouver style)

```
type={database on the Internet}
```

and not

```
type={page on the Internet}
```

In fact, with the following contents for your `ex.bib`

```
@Webpage{arXiv-web,
    type={database on the Internet},
    title={arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    key={arXiv.org e-Print archive},
    url={http://arxiv.org},
    note = {Accessed: 2014-02-03}
}
```

the output of the document will be:

[image]

Note, however, that the `year` field should be required. Adding, for example,

```
year={2014}
```

the result will be

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inserting a `year` field will help resolve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be helpful if you could explain how one does this and how it answers the question.